# changing existing COM+ applications identity via vbs script

Tags: .net, vbscript, com+, msdtc

How to changing existing COM+ applications identity via vbs script. like Authentication level = none and identity to this user via vb scripts. found many posting on add/delete com+ applications but not changing existing one. please help

Answer (score 3):

Here's a script that retrieves all of the applications, finds the one with the name you are interested in and sets the Identity, Password and [Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686107%28VS.85%29.aspx#authentication) to Connect.  For a full list of Application properties see [Applications Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686107%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) under [COM+ Administration Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687763%28VS.85%29.aspx).

```
Const COMAdminAuthenticationDefault   = 0
Const COMAdminAuthenticationNone      = 1
Const COMAdminAuthenticationConnect   = 2
Const COMAdminAuthenticationCall      = 3
Const COMAdminAuthenticationPacket    = 4 
Const COMAdminAuthenticationIntegrity = 5
Const COMAdminAuthenticationPrivacy   = 6

Dim catalog
Dim applications
Dim application

Set catalog = CreateObject("COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog")
Set applications = catalog.GetCollection("Applications")

Call applications.Populate

For Each application In applications

    If (application.value("Name")  = "AppName") Then

        application.Value("Authentication") = COMAdminAuthenticationConnect
        application.Value("Identity") = "domain\account"
        application.Value("Password") = "Password"

        Call applications.SaveChanges
    End If
Next
```