# Powershell to set TransactionIsolation level of COM Plus components

Tags: powershell, com, powershell-2.0

How can i set the TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL OF COM PLUS components to Any through powershell script.
I am trying with following code

```
  $comAdmin = New-Object -comobject COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog
    $apps = $comAdmin.GetCollection(“Applications”)
    $apps.Populate();

    foreach($app in $apps)
    {
    Write-Host $app.Name
        if($app.Name -eq $ApplicationName)
        {
         $components = $apps.GetCollection("Components",$app.key)
         $components.Populate()


             foreach ($component in $components)
             {
                $componentName = $component.Name;                
                Write-Host "*"$componentName;   
                if($componentName -eq "WDA_DUP.Generic13")
                {
                $component.Value("TXIsolationLevel")=COMAdminTxIsolationLevelAny;
                }                  
             } 
        }   
    }
```

But not getting the purpose solved.Please Help me :)
     `

Comment: Have you tried to replace COMAdminTxIsolationLevelAny by 0? (its underlying enum value: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms681736.aspx )

Comment: Yes i tried,but ended up with following error:                 Exception setting "Value": "The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))"

Comment: Your script seems wrong in the first place, you need to put `$component.Value("TXIsolationLevel")=0` (without ;)

Comment: Hi Simon,thank you so much for the reply,I removed semi colon,and now the error is gone.But the new transaction isolation level is not reflected in the component service console when i am seeing for the component.How can i check if its really set to 0 or not.

Comment: You need to call SaveChanges somehow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508874/powershell-com-settings

Comment: I already did that,it did not help.I called savechanges on $components,$component asw well as $apps.

Comment: $component.Value("TXIsolationLevel") ... should be TxIsolationLevel (with a lower case x).

Comment: @DavidBrabant I tried this david,its not working

Comment: @DavidBrabant Hey David,It worked finally.Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Working script:

```
$ApplicationID = "{C0D4E2A4-CAC1-47BA-819C-EAB73E978FDF}"
$comAdmin = New-Object -comobject COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog
$apps = $comAdmin.GetCollection(“Applications”)
$apps.Populate();

foreach($app in $apps)
{
  #Write-Host $app.Name
  #Write-Host $app.Key
  if($app.Key -eq $ApplicationID)
  {
      Write-Host $app.Name
      $components = $apps.GetCollection("Components",$app.key)
      $components.Populate()
      foreach ($component in $components)
      {
        $componentName = $component.Name;                
        Write-Host "Set "$componentName;   
        $component.Value("TxIsolationLevel")=2
      } 
      $components.SaveChanges()
  }   
}
```

Comment: consider adding details of your answer so that the OP can understand what was the error