# use powershell to set component services transaction timeout

Tags: powershell, com

I'm trying to automate an application deployment using Powershell.
One step requires that I go into Component Services to My Computer properties and set the Transaction timeout to 0.

The answer at [Powershell COM+ settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508874/powershell-com-settings) seems the most promising answer to me, but I've been unable to map the Transaction Timeout setting.

Looking at the COM+ Administration Collections page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687763(v=vs.85).aspx I see there is a LocalComputer collection but I'm unable to retrieve a properties collection from the LocalComputer collection object, which is where I guess the Transaction Timeout property would be.

Here's my little exploratory code:

```
$comAdmin = New-Object -com ("COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog.1")

$applications = $comAdmin.GetCollection("LocalComputer")
$applications.Populate()

$properties = $applications.GetCollection("PropertyInfo",$application.key)
foreach ($property in $properties){
    Write-Host $property.name
}
```

Can anyone help me set the Transaction Timout?

Update: This script at least gets me the TransactionTimeout value:

```
$comAdmin = New-Object -com ("COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog.1")
$LocalColl = $comAdmin.Connect("localhost")
$LocalComputer = $LocalColl.GetCollection("LocalComputer",$LocalColl.Name)
$LocalComputer.Populate()

$LocalComputerItem = $LocalComputer.Item(0)


$LocalComputerItem.Value("TransactionTimeout")
```

Comment: The LocalComputer description at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682790(v=vs.85).aspx lists the TransactionTimeout property. But I can't figure out how to access the properties of the LocalComputer collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the working code:

```
$comAdmin = New-Object -com ("COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog.1")
$LocalColl = $comAdmin.Connect("localhost")
$LocalComputer = $LocalColl.GetCollection("LocalComputer",$LocalColl.Name)
$LocalComputer.Populate()

$LocalComputerItem = $LocalComputer.Item(0)
$CurrVal = $LocalComputerItem.Value("TransactionTimeout")
Write-Host "Transaction Timeout = $CurrVal"

$LocalComputerItem.Value("TransactionTimeout") = 20
$LocalComputer.SaveChanges()
```

I didn't think it was saving the changes because everytime I checked the Component Services | LocalComputer | Properties | Transaction Timeout it was still '60', even after I refreshed all components. I finally exited Component Services and came back in, then it had the '20' value.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted call this PowerShell script from an external tool/utility/batch file (such as during automated software deployment), then it may help if the before and after values for the timeout were displayed (and formatted nicely with new lines - for log redirection):

```
$comAdmin = New-Object -com ("COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog.1")
$LocalColl = $comAdmin.Connect("localhost")
$LocalComputer = $LocalColl.GetCollection("LocalComputer",$LocalColl.Name)
$LocalComputer.Populate()

$LocalComputerItem = $LocalComputer.Item(0)
$CurrVal = $LocalComputerItem.Value("TransactionTimeout")
Write-Host "Old Transaction Timeout = $CurrVal`r`n"

$LocalComputerItem.Value("TransactionTimeout") = 180
$CurrVal = $LocalComputerItem.Value("TransactionTimeout")
Write-Host "New Transaction Timeout = $CurrVal`r`n"
$LocalComputer.SaveChanges()
```

Assuming you saved the code above to a file called `Set-Component-Services-Timeout.ps1`, then this could then be called from anywhere with a command like this:

```
powershell.exe -Command .\Set-Component-Services-Timeout.ps1 >> log_file.txt 2>&1
```