# Get Identity Windows Com+ Application?

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript, com+

I have found where I can SET the Identity for Com+ Applications, but cannot find how to GET the Identity for existing Com+ Applications.

set:
[How to modify COM+ applications from powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729018/how-to-modify-com-applications-from-powershell)

get the COM+ application name, ID, and whether it is running:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/projectserver/en-US/7b035318-fc4c-41bb-ad9a-33fa51485c57/check-whether-aplication-in-comadmincomadmincatalog-is-running-or-not?forum=ITCG

```
Dim Catalog, AppCollection, AppList, AppItem
Set Catalog = CreateObject("COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog")
Set AppCollection = Catalog.GetCollection("Applications")
AppCollection.Populate
Set AppList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each AppItem In AppCollection
  AppList.Add AppItem.Value("ID"), AppItem.Name
Next

Dim AppInstances, AppInstance, AppInstanceList, Value
Set AppInstances = Catalog.GetCollection("ApplicationInstances")
AppInstances.Populate
Set AppInstanceList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each AppInstance In AppInstances
  Value = AppInstance.Value("Application")
  AppInstanceList.Add Value, AppList(Value)
Next

For Each AppItem In AppList
  WScript.Echo vbNewLine _
    & "App Name: " & vbTab & AppList(AppItem) & vbNewLine _
    & "App ID: " & vbTab & AppItem & vbNewLine _
    & "Running? " & vbTab & CStr(AppInstanceList.Exists(AppItem))
Next
```

So I figured if I change the item **'AppItem.Value("ID")'**, to **'AppItem.Value("Identity")'**, that would give me what I am looking for, but I get error ---

```
Script:  c:\pathtofile\test.vbs
Line:    7
Char:    3
Error:   This key is already associated with an element of this collection
Code:    800A01C9
Source:  Microsoft VBScript runtime error
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow! please include the parts of the link you need to support your question in the question. Also, you need to show what you have tried which is not working so that people here can help you

Answer (score 0):

```
Const COMAdminAuthenticationDefault   = 0
Const COMAdminAuthenticationNone      = 1
Const COMAdminAuthenticationConnect   = 2
Const COMAdminAuthenticationCall      = 3
Const COMAdminAuthenticationPacket    = 4 
Const COMAdminAuthenticationIntegrity = 5
Const COMAdminAuthenticationPrivacy   = 6

Dim catalog
Dim applications
Dim application

Set catalog = CreateObject("COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog")
Set applications = catalog.GetCollection("Applications")

Call applications.Populate

For Each application In applications

    If (application.value("Identity")  = "domain\username") Then

Wscript.Echo application.value("Name")

        Call applications.SaveChanges
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Modified https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133531/changing-existing-com-applications-identity-via-vbs-script

Thank you Yan!!!

https://stackoverflow.com/users/274535/yan-sklyarenko

Comment: I mean thanks Randy...

https://stackoverflow.com/users/114664/randy-levy